# Quickest way from London to Dubai without flying?

Tags: public-transport, uk, overland, uae

This is a question from a friend not (yet!) on Travel.SE...

From London, what is the quickest way to get to Dubai (via trains, buses, ferries etc) without flying?

(My usual advice of "just check [Seat61](http://www.seat61.com/)" seems to fall down in this case, as they don't seem to have a UAE entry in their destination list...)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I suggest:

- Eurostar from London to Paris (2h30) or to Brussels (2h00)
- Train to Istanbul (47 to 49h)
- Train to Tehran (66h)
- Bus to Bandar-e-Abbas
- Ferry to Dubaï

Train may be faster and more comfortable in Europe.
Bus may be faster and more comfortable in Middle-East.

Information sites are:

- Train in Europe: [Any HAFAS site](http://plannerint.b-rail.be/) (I choose multilingual belgian site)
- Turkey: [Turkey travel planner](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/)
- Iran: [Iran travelling center](http://www.irantravelingcenter.com/)

## Update (Nov. 2017)

Trans Asia Express, the train between Turkey and Iran, is suspended since July 2015. See [Is Trans Asia Express still running?](https://travel.railturkey.org/2016/05/31/is-trans-asia-express-still-running/) on Rail Turkey Travel for more information. An alternative is (found at [Orient Bahn Reisen](http://www.orientbahn-reisen.de/de/aktuelles/#turkey-to-iran-train), or at [Seat61](https://www.seat61.com/Iran.htm#.V9MVNkW6nCS) but otherwise not verified):

- Train from Istanbul to Ankara
- Train to Tatvan
- Bus to Van
- Bus to Tabriz
- Train to Tehran

Comment: impressive !  ..

Comment: Except... the train from Istanbul to Tehran is not running at the moment. I think the train also still starts a while out of Istanbul due to construction work. While the cross-border connection was cancelled a while back due to unrest in the area.

Comment: @MastaBaba - I finally updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ha! I did not realise this was such an old post.

Answer (score 8):

There is no railway in UAE, so the only choice is sea-travel or buses.
In the persian gulf you can use the [internal ships](http://www.irantravelingcenter.com/valfajr8_persian_gulf.htm), from BANDAR LENGEH to DUBAI - it costs $100 one way.

I can't find any [specific info](http://www.travellerspoint.com/guide/International_ferries/#Middle_East) about ferries from Europe to the UAE, so maybe the best way is to get a ferry to Egypt, and from there use the bus.

Note that the large government company [IRISL](http://www.irisl.net/documents/document/0/11589/portal.aspx) has some ships to Europe, but doesn't indicate whether there are places for passengers.

Comment: Any comments to downvoter?

Comment: There are no ferries from Europe to Egypt.

Comment: @gerrit Back then 10 years ago I probably meant that there are ferries from OAE or Jordan to Egypt, and one can go by land there, for example, as following: Greece -> ferry to Turkey -> car to Jordan -> ferry to Egypt, or similar layout

Answer (score 4):

I also suggest:

- London to Paris by Eurostar (2h30)
- Paris to Milan by high-speed TGV
- Milan to Bari by Frecciabianca
- Bari to Dubrovnik by Jadrolinija ferry
- bus from Dubrovnik to Split
- train to Zagreb and then to Istanbul
- train to Tehran
- bus to Bandar-e-Abbas
- ferry to Dubai

or else, you can ride the TGV Lyria to Zurich, Chur, and then the Bernina Express to Tirano and a Trenitalia train to Milan, instead of TGV Paris-Milan.