# Is it possible to travel by car from Europe to Thailand?

Tags: borders, road-trips, asia, countries, geography

Since mainland Thailand and India on mainland Asia are land connected with mainland Europe, would it be physically possible to travel by car from, for example, [Frankfurt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt), Germany to [Pattaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattaya), Thailand, or [Delhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delhi), India?

What I mean by this is that: Are there any roads linking mainland Europe, like Germany, with mainland Asia Thailand?

Comment: The problems are not roads (which do exist), but border crossings. You would require a whole stack of Visas and permits and research if you are allowed to bring your own vehicle across the border. Pretty much all routes will include countries that are very restrictive and not very travel friendly.

Comment: I did it by train, bus, and boat many years ago.  Even then, it would have been hard to have a car with me.  One leg was a 6 day boat ride from Madras (as it was at the time) to Penang.  The boat did not take cars and it ceased to run long ago.  Some of the crossings I made are harder or impossible today.

Comment: I did it from London to Mongolia in 2011.  Hard work, trains, buses, cars, but the roads certainly exist. Border guards and visas are the biggest issue.

Comment: Worth the read: https://www.mylondon.news/news/zone-1-news/incredible-london-bus-route-once-18614075

Comment: Two Finnish guys drove a tuk-tuk (auto rickshaw) from Thailand to Finland around ten years ago. They managed it, but it took 10 months, was not easy and it's probably harder these days. In an interview before the trip their route plan was Myanmar-Nepal-India-Pakistan-Iran-Azerbaijan-Georgia-Russia-Ukraine-Belarus-Lithuania-Latvia-Estonia, but I'm not sure what the final route they took was.

Comment: @Dronir Sadly, both Myanmar and Iran have become much less safe and stable in the past 10 years. :-(

Comment: A comment on the form of the question: Yes, it is "possible." An example of the impossible is the anecdote about the baseball player Rickey Henderson. Someone suggested to him, when he was playing in the USA, that he could play winter baseball in the Dominican Republic. He asked, "How long does it take to drive there?" I think the question asks, "Is it practical?"

Comment: Another question by same asker: [Can you drive from Europe to the Middle East?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/179294/47309) that involves some of the same borders...

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Travelling today, probably Ukraine is the most unsafe state on that itinerary.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni probably yes, but apart from the (extremely dangerous) battlefields, the probability of being hit by a missile is not much different from the probability of getting kidnapped in Pakistan or Myanmar... Anyway, Ukraine can't even be entered from Russia, the border is completely closed.

Comment: There's a big block of land between them that I wouldn't travel through, never mind it being technically and legally possible. Which is a shame because what an adventure that would be.

Comment: @Hilmar .. *"Pretty much all routes will include countries that are very restrictive and not very travel friendly"*  But you only go through Russia and China.  I'm not sure if that's a correct summary of Russia / China.  (Noticing my answer, sure, the "red route" is inconceivable, but nobody would drive that way if you hopped in a car and "drove to Thailand.)

Answer (score 49):

In order to get from Europe to Thailand by car, you would have to pass through at least one of these three countries: Afghanistan, Iran, or China.

- Afghanistan: extremely dangerous and unstable. Out of question.
- Iran: unstable, unpredictable, and under international sanctions. Additionally, a journey through Iran would take you into countries such as Pakistan and later Myanmar (provided you manage to cross all the borders), that are also unstable and dangerous.
- China: severely restricts entry of foreign-registered motor vehicles, and also doesn't accept foreign driving licenses (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit). It's possible to obtain a provisional Chinese driving permit, but that can't be requested at a road border checkpoint, it must be requested in advance in China (e.g. at a major airport). Getting an entry permit for your car requires special arrangements, takes a lot of time and energy, and those who obtain it must be accompanied by a local Chinese guide at all times until they leave the country. Additionally, China still (as of Feb 2023) doesn't issue tourist visas.

**To sum up, driving a car from Europe to Thailand is next to impossible.** It would be a remarkable feat requiring an extremely capable and resourceful traveler. That's why most casual adventurers from Europe would end their road trips in Vladivostok, Russia.

Alternately, I've read about people who travelled from Europe to Southeast Asia via China by bicycle. Bicycles need little to no paperwork and cyclists need no driving licenses. This is not for everyone, but it's doable. Cycling can of course be freely combined with train travel.

Comment: *Bicycles need no paperwork* — AFAIK they do for Russia, and some countries do not allow entering by bike.  A friend who cycled to Mongolia did a few hundred metres on the back of a pick-up truck because a border crossing somewhere in Central Asia did not allow crossing by bicycle.  He still sat on his bike as he was in the pick-up truck, so he could claim to have done the entire route by bicycle ;-)

Comment: @gerrit Russia doesn't allow entering by bike? That's news to me. There are for sure many road border checkpoints that don't allow crossing on foot or by bicycle (usually those on major roads, used by heavy trucks). But there are also ones where it's possible, such as the Narva-Ivangorod checkpoint. Anyway, given the magnitude of a transcontinental bike travel, crossing the border in someone's pickup truck sounds like a minor inconvenience, not a deal breaker.

Comment: Russia does allow entering by bike, but I seem to recall there is some paperwork to fill.  It was somewhere in Central Asia that they were not allowed to cross by bike, perhaps entering Kazakhstan or Mongolia (not sure).  I agree that crossing into Mongolia in the back up a pick-up truck at a remote border crossing just adds to the adventure and is not a deal breaker on this type of journey :)

Comment: You can apply in China for Provisional Driving Permits, even as a tourist. It would require traveling to China for this permit before departure, as it cannot be obtained on borders.

Comment: The OP doesn't stipulate the nationality of the driver(s). Seems like it may not be that difficult... provided a licensed Chinese national was participating.

Comment: Some land borders explicitly do not allow bicycles and pedestrians (eg - Singapore - Malaysia, Tuas Link).

Comment: @nothrow Interesting. Is it only about filling in some forms, or does one have to take a Chinese driving school and pass the exams?

Comment: Can you offer some references to back up your claims about the dangers of Iran and Pakistan? Granted, the past few months have been interesting for Iran, but overall and despite the sanctions, I don't know that it would be a problem to pass through those countries. I guess it might be an issue if you try with a US passport (even that would likely be OK for Pakistan though, right?), but for the rest of the world?

Comment: @terdon Iran is not dangerous to tourists per se (although many things can go wrong there). However, Pakistan IS dangerous to tourists (Balochistan - the region bordering Iran - is considered dangerous by the UK FCDO https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/pakistan), crossing from there into India is very complicated, and then you will have to face another problem of getting into and out of very unstable Myanmar.

Comment: I would be MUCH more worried of Pakistan, rather than Iran. E.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kidnapping_of_Czech_tourists_in_Balochistan

Comment: These people did manage to cross China by their cars https://www.idnes.cz/cestovani/kolem-sveta/trabantem-tam-a-zase-zpatky-cina-kyrgyzstan-uzbekistan-samarkand-rusko-ukrajina-uzhorod-zluty-cirkus.A180815_162909_kolem-sveta_hig  It was very difficult and a guide was required so that do not stray into locations they are not permitted to see.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko yeah, Myanmar is a whole different issue. It was Iran that surprised me, and Pakistan. I was not aware of the problems in the specific region you mentioned. That makes sense, thanks.

Comment: A provisional driving authorization can be issued on the spot against a foreign driving licence (with Chinese translation by certified translators in China) in several airports (at least PVG, PEK and HAK) in China; or at the designated provincial traffic control offices outside airports. It is much more complicated to import a foreign-registered car for a nonresident though.

Comment: I've spoken with a man who drove, with his son, across China to Eastern Europe. He started on the south coast of China. I don't know what the S.E.A. borders are like now, China is building some big roads there but I don't know how far they've got.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: 'Cycling can be freely combined with train travel' - yes it can be, but often isn't *allowed* to. In the UK the anti-cycling lobby constantly finds more ways to make life difficult. It's harder to take your bike on a train than it was 10 years ago. Even if it is allowed, overcrowding is often so bad that it's simply not possible. It's reckless to travel across dozens of countries and assume that you'll be able to let the train take the strain in every single one, on any arbitrary train route.

Comment: This answer would seem to be simply wrong.  Here's someone doing it: https://lesmacax.wordpress.com  Sure, it's difficult.

Comment: @Fattie I'd say that "next to impossible" is a fairly good summary of how difficult it is. I've edited the information about China to make it more accurate, but it still is a very difficult undertaking. IMO, OP is not an experienced traveller (given the fact they asked about roads...), so this answer is useful to them.

Answer (score 28):

It is actually possible. Definitely not easy but feasible. A friend of mine did this a little over 3 years ago, driving from Paris to Kuala Lumpur, passing through Russia, Mongolia and China. It took and her family about a year to explore the way and she said it took almost that long to plan it! The trip is documented online - in French - on her [blog here](https://lesmacax.wordpress.com/). This is a rare adventure and they were even met with a TV crew part of the way from Russia to China which can be [seen here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPpSUWZQYX_dWltMp8B9BSO_ksBAg_FgtR2Uu-k1-IP8X_xCG6PQX-gvxTp739eBg?key=ZTF3Sm04Y0VpWlpNb3k2YVYwSDNtQ2NLU1FTeFpB).

The plan relies on traversing a significant portion of Russia to avoid some of the dangerous countries south of it. The path can be shown on the blog and there are several pages that explain the [planning process](https://lesmacax.wordpress.com/preparatifs/). The greatest difficulty is timing since most visas have a validity period and a stay limit. Given that these visas also have to be stamped onto passports, it was sometimes necessary to stop near a border, do a visa application locally and then move through the border. China was particularly complicated given that they had constraints of having to go through an agency and they were met by someone in China that escorted them while driving through until Malaysia, crossing Thailand on the way there.

There are roads the entire way and although varying in quality, they managed to cross using an RV. A regular car should have no trouble following the same path. In fact, the RV complicated matters because some visas ask for stay location and hotel information.

Note that for the return, they did not want to retrace their steps and so opted to come back via the South. As mentioned already this is rather difficult and risk proposition, so the opted to ferry the RV from Malasia to Dubai and returned driving to Paris from there (after another short ferry to Iran).

Comment: *”[…] driving through until Malaysia.”* I think you meant Myanmar or Laos, the two countries that sit between China and Thailand.

Comment: The end point was Malaysia but they did pass through Laos and Thailand. The map is available from the link on top of the blog.

Comment: Check what you wrote: *"[…] until Malaysia. From there they crossed to Thailand."* I checked the map and they definitely did not cross from Malaysia to Thailand, but the opposite. They were escorted in China until what point? From the map I assume they were escorted  until the China-Laos border, which your answer doesn't make clear. If they *were* escorted until Malaysia, then just *"From there they crossed to Thailand."* isn't correct.

Comment: Clarified and, yes, indeed the were escorted to the Laos border.

Answer (score 15):

There are roads and [famous journeys using them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Usage_du_monde) so it's possible in that sense (there is nothing like the [Darién gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dari%C3%A9n_Gap) on the Eurasian landmass). Customs (for the car) and visas will not be trivial to sort out but I have heard about people managing that, even as recently as the late 2010s (either using public transportation or with a motorbike). The main problem will be finding a route that is open and safe, depending on your citizenship.

The classic route from Europe to India goes over Iran and Afghanistan. It was popular from the 1950s to the 1970s but became very dangerous after the [start of a long series of wars in Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afghanistan_conflict_(1978%E2%80%93present)). Iran was better but it is currently under international sanctions, experiencing a lot of turmoil and generally more dangerous that it has ever been in my lifetime. Afghanistan has always been challenging and has probably gotten even more dangerous lately. Even people who relish the lack of infrastructure and the instability ought to be concerned with the high risk of kidnapping for ransom. Pakistan is open (actually have a friend who went there for a short visit a couple of months ago) but the border areas are considered more dangerous so overland travel does not seem realistic.

For South-East Asia, you could consider going over Russia, Mongolia, and China but not with your own vehicle (see Johnnyjanko's answer about that). I think all these countries are technically open for visitors.  Relation between European countries and Russia are tense but it is not necessarily [in the “do not travel” category just yet](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/aussenpolitik/laender/russischefoederation-node/russischefoederationsicherheit/201536). One question is how to get to Russia from Germany. The border with Ukraine is obviously closed, not sure it's possible to reach Belarus from Poland. Baltic countries have been talking about banning visitors from Russia but maybe you could still cross the border in the other direction or go all the way to Finland?

Further East, I believe China has officially reopened its borders to visitors after a long freeze in relation to the Covid pandemic but I am not sure there are many visas or visitors just yet. Some regions also require additional paperwork making overland travel more difficult. Myanmar is completely off-limits so going overland from India is impossible and Laos is the only options from China (or Vietnam but it does not share a border with Thailand). There is also one border crossing between China and Laos that may be passable.

Compared to all these countries, Thailand is safe, open, and easy to travel to. I know several people who visited recently. They all came by air but overland travel has historically been possible and I don't see any sign that its borders are closed.

Comment: Foreign tourists are not permitted to drive their cars into China, see my answer.

Comment: Latvian / Estonian / Finnish borders with Russia are still open. If you have a valid Russian visa, you can enter Russia. It takes a long time and a lot of paperwork to enter with a car, but it's possible. It is not possible to enter Russia from Ukraine (border closed) and Belarus (land border closed for 3rd party nationals - only citizens of Russia and Belarus are allowed to cross).

Comment: To my knowledge China is currently not giving out tourist visas (at least to Europeans). They recently became a lot more open about visas for visiting family and some business visa were available even through all of Corona but afaik no tourist visas are available as of now.

Comment: @quarague Yes, that's also true, but it can be reasonably expected that they'll start issuing tourist visas again at some point. However, the situation around foreign driving licenses can't be expected to change in the forseeable future...

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Interesting thanks. It's much more common to do that particular part of the journey by train but I seem to recall reading about someone going to Asia on a motorbike, does that make a difference to the driving licence issue? Or maybe they stopped in Mongolia or somewhere in Central Asia.

Comment: @Relaxed Most likely their motorbike journeys ended in Russia (Siberia), Central Asia or Mongolia. China is a no-go zone for vehicles with foreign license plates and for drivers with foreign driving permits. Can you please update your answer with these information?

Comment: @Johnnyjanko What part do you think need editing? I don't have anything to add to the info you provided.

Comment: @Relaxed well, you mention the possibility of travelling via China. IMO your answer should include the information that driving through China is NOT possible, otherwise it's misleading (not everyone reads the comments).

Comment: @Johnnyjanko I added a reference to your answer. Ultimately, the question is pretty broad, as I make clear in the first paragraph I cover different routes and different means of transportations and there is a lot of info we simply do not have.

Comment: [I have read that](https://caravanistan.com/transport/driving/iran/) there is the possibility of hiring a guide to allow you to transit through Iran, and possibly this works in other countries. Reports about the ease of traveling in Iran vary widely, and it probably varies a lot depending on the local political situation (probably not great right now) and their international relations.

Answer (score 9):

Answering the actual question asked:

> Are there any roads connecting mainland Europe, like Germany, with
> mainland Asia Thailand?

Yes, there are.

Google Maps will refuse to calculate a route from Germany to Thailand, but you can get it to give you a route from, say, Frankfurt to Teheran as well as one from Jalandhar (India, just after the border to Pakistan) to wherever in Thailand you want. The stated driving times for these are around 50 and 80 hours, respectively. If you drive 8-10 hours a day, that's just over 2 weeks.

The part between Teheran and Jalandhar does have major roads, at least on the map. Also, none of the Google Maps routes indicate that you need to take a ferry somewhere. So yes, there are roads and you can, theoretically, drive from Germany to Thailand without leaving your car (well, except for pumping gas and visiting the toilet).

You CAN get a route from Openstreetmap:

https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_car&route=50.111%2C8.682%3B12.937%2C100.886#map=4/33.91/54.84

Which shows up as 12323 km and 145.5 hours. It's pretty similar to what I wrote above, bypassing Teheran on the highway and going through Jalandhar.

The northern route (calculate in 2 parts, Openstreetmap doesn't do intermediate stops) could be Frankfurt-Omsk-Pattaya. That route bypasses Ukraine, where, to put it mildly, some of the mapped roads may not exist anymore.

Whether or not any of that is a good ideas has already been answered extensively in other answers.

Answer (score 5):

Borders and safety are going to be a big problem.

I have done a "tour" that went from Katmandu, Nepal, through New Delhi, India (where we joined it) to Tehran, Iran--it continued on to London, England but that's where our plans went a different way.

Interesting in 1975.  Crazy unsafe (Pakistan), probably impossible (Afghanistan) and certainly impossible (Iran--we have US passports) now.  The Afghanistan portion could be routed around, but Pakistan and Iran remain big problems.  This was a bus, if it could get through any ordinary passenger vehicle should likewise be able to.

Comment: Why would Iran be impossible?

Comment: @gerrit I guess because they have us passports

Comment: @BЈовић There's no ban on people with US passports entering Iran, is there?  The reverse was true for a while (with exceptions) but that ban has been lifted.

Comment: There's no ban, but they must be accompanied by an official guide at all times, in addition to being subjected to increased attention from the authorities. For sure they can't cross Iran in a private vehicle.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Apparently the things have changed since the last time I looked at it.  US passports used to be forbidden.

Answer (score 5):

The route through China might be difficult for cars in terms of getting permits but you can definitely consider motorbikes or bicycles.

India to Europe has been done very recently too, [like these guys going from Bangalore, India to London, UK through China and Russia](https://youtu.be/uDlz01lFHPk)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that these guys had to make LOTS of special arrangements and get lots of permits not available to casual tourists. Not only because of China, but also Bhutan is very restrictive. 2 years of planning...

Comment: @Johnnyjanko Is anybody going to India overland a casual tourist?

Comment: @Relaxed Of course, anyone who completes such a journey is not a casual tourist. IMO, OP is a casual tourist so the answer should be targeted at them.

Comment: @Relaxed Taking the train to India is [doable](https://www.seat61.com/europe-to-india-overland.htm) — not super-easy, but also not "you'll be on television" type expedition difficult.

Comment: @gerrit Maybe, although I would dispute that going through Iran and Pakistan is that realistic nowadays. Still doesn't feel “casual” to me but it's a bit subjective I guess.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in theory it's possible and it has been done. There was a famous bus ride that departed from Salo, Finland for Bangkok, Thailand back in 2018. The bus made it to Bangkok and it was possible to buy tickets to go on this trip. Obviously things have changed since then, since the routing required driving through Russia, which would be next to impossible these days. The blog can be found [here](https://www.rantapallo.fi/pikavuoro/).

Answer (score 2):

#### Answering the *specific question*:

> would it be **physically possible** to drive from [Germany to Thailand]

> What I **mean is** that: Are there any **roads connecting** mainland Europe ... with Thailand

#### The simple answer is "yes", there are two ways to go:

[image]

1. The normal simple route (blue) is you just drive through Russia then China.  (The "high road," if you will.) It's that easy. Hop in your car and turn on the GPS.
2. Alternately you can take the "low road" shown in red. There are any number of variations and you pass through 10 or so countries.

#### Driving conditions

You pass over no water. It's generally flat.

On the normal (blue) road all roads are sealed and straightforward.

#### Could it be your question is about *The Himalayas*?

The question "is Berlin connected to Bangkok by land" is trivially answered by glancing at a globe.

For young people reading, I highly recommend opening "google maps" and if you zoom way out you can get a good understanding of this planet.

However, notice the **area marked in pink**. If you go there you will find a really, I mean really, big mountainous region of this planet. It's basically not possible to drive through it.

It could be that the sense of your question is basically "can I drive through the Himalayas?". Answer, no, you just go "above" them, ie drive through Russia and China.

## Addendum - paperwork

#### Current political conditions (2023)

Blue route:

As of writing, Russia (the large country at the upper part of this planet which defeated Nazi Germany 80 years ago) is having a war that is apparently disapproved of by some/most political figures in the USA.

**Every single web reference I can find states that it's still perfectly possible to travel to Russia** ([random example](https://russiable.com/foreigners-travel-russia-requirements-coronavirus/))

OP is not a USA citizen so the issue seems irrelevant.

(If you're a USA citizen and reading this, it seems the USA government has put up many pages on the web stating that they "recommend" USA citizens don't travel to Russia currently. However, every serious reference I can find states that travel to Russia (for US citizens) is perfectly possible and normal ([random example](https://www.sfgate.com/travel/article/can-americans-travel-to-russia-16978440.php)).

Red route:

You would have to travel through the regions of "Chaos-stan" as it's sometimes called.

This is a full-on chaotic war zone with irregular and ad-hoc social and political structures.

#### China paperwork addendum:

It is notoriously a HUGE paperwork fuss to drive in China and/or take your own car in to China.

It's perfectly possible, and people do it every day, it's just a huge, huge, fuss.

## Road conditions

Obviously, China has far and away the best roads on the planet.

They are so far ahead, and getting further ahead every month, there isn't even a second place.

(Much as Germany had the best roads on the planet in, say, the 1950s [they are now all falling apart] and the US had OK roads in say the 1970s [they have all fallen apart].)

(Also, of course, obviously, China is far and away the world's biggest car maker and, if I'm not mistaken, the biggest purchasor of cars. It is a completely car-obsessed country, it's the #1 "car nation".)

There are any number of major TV documentaries about the wonders of driving in China, including say

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-XDxCb92X4

(I encourage you to watch this if you're unfamiliar with the roads there.)

(Note that that documentary is very out of date, roads in China are now another huge leap ahead.)

Actually, in the same show they take a number of **foreign cars** in to China (as well as driving local cars) so you can also see that process.

## Summary

1. The question at hand is about the **physical** connection. Since, obviously, Germany/Thailand are on the same landmass for the last few million years, answer is "yes".
2. Hence, I believe the actual sense of the OPs question was perhaps about "The Himalayas". You can not drive through them. You go either above or below them.

Geopolitics issues: the "red" route goes through the planet's current "region of unrest", in short "an anarchic war zone".

---

*addendum sealed roads*.  It's commonplace to drive across Russia. I understood that it's all sealed, but it's unclear, some of the road may be unsealed. IDK. You can google any number of articles "drive across Russia" `[example][4]`

Comment: Not only the USA opposes Russia in this war and how Russia is going to react on the other countries can change over time. China is also at odds with a couple of countries, so I would call your blue route also not free of war risks.

Comment: Hmm, "that something might happen in the future" is always possible. Today, Friday, I stated the situation accurately.  The QA is not about predicting what might happen. Cheers

Comment: (Regarding what "will likely happen", in say the "few years" time scale, it's a certainty the USA/Russia will swap again to supposed friendly mode, that Putin guy will eventually pass away, etc. So in the long run, the USA will remove their web sites stating "we suggest you don't go to Russia." Recall that as we speak, USA citizens are going to and from Russia as normal, they're just web site texts. And the OP is not from the USA, nor are most readers of this web site (owned by Belgians I believe?!)  If any downvoters have a reason, please do tell !!!)

Comment: Actually, I may delete those two comments. The specific question on the page is about physical geography. *("would it be physically possible to drive from [Germany to Thailand]")*  All of the chat on this page, including mine, about geopolitics, is not relevant.