Trip from Germany to Japan by motorhome?
So basically me and four of my friends have always wanted to go to Japan. But we also wanted to make a road trip out of it. Now we are thinking about getting a motorhome (nothing fancy something lowkey like a Laika X 580, but we'll install a solarpanel and starlink). We'd start by driving from Germany through the south of Russia until Irkutsk. Then driving vertically through Mongolia to the Zamiin-Uud Border Control Station and then to Shanghai. We would stay there for a couple of days, drive back up to Qingdao, take a ferry to South Korea, drive to the south of South Korea and then to Japan. Then we will stay in Japan for a couple of weeks and the last two weeks will be in Tokyo where we will sell the motorhome and fly back.
We want to drive through Russia since we figure it will be safer that way than driving south through Iran and India etc.... Also the roads in the south suck, so that's why we want to drive through Russia. The trip will be when the war is over, so we have some time to plan.
What do you guys think of the idea and what are some aspects to keep in mind?

This question is far too broad and opinion-based IMHO.

Selling a left-hand-drive vehicle in a right-hand-drive country is probably going to be difficult. There will probably be issues with other technical specs as well. But there are many other problems before that, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179531/is-it-possible-to-travel-by-car-from-europe-to-thailand for the main stumbling blocks (China) on a similar route.

See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78835/30703 and https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/111370/30703

Go to your automobile club and check what data they have on all country you will drive: you may need special insurances, some modification (maybe just tape) on some lights, etc. And ask to the other people which did it. (you are not the only one with such idea). To central Asia I saw German motorbikes, few EU cars, and various EU lorries.

IMHO: if you go in Russia, go to the end, and then ferry to Korea and Japan: reduce crossing borders.

Even if you could get starlink reception in Russia, I would not want to explain to Russian authorities why in the midst of a war you are driving around their country with a mobile internet connection that they can't control.

@GiacomoCatenazzi good advice, but the first place to check on insurance restrictions is with your insurer.  Also the conditions on cross-border commercial freight traffic probably have little bearing on personal travel, though it is interesting to note.

'Tokyo where we will sell the motorhome': the motorhome would then be subject to some form of import tax (you are taking in goods that will remain in Japan), which should be taken into consideration.

Big problem with your plan is China which doesn't let foreign vehicles in. That said, I think Russia-Japan ferries may exist?

@CMaster 'China which doesn't let foreign vehicles in': Expanding on that would be a good (partial) answer - before the question is closed. There may be future readers that would benifit from sich an answer.

@CMaster apparently it’s actually possible, but requires quite a bit of paperwork (for both the driver and the vehicle), may need to be done in advance, may require an agent, may require an escort/guide…

@CMaster apparently the Russia-Japan ferry has been discontinued, so Russia-Korea then Korea-Japan are on order. But it’s far from obvious they take cars and not just foot passengers.

While the question is a bit broad, we’ve had similar questions over the years which got good answers, though most of them are a bit old (mostly pre-Covid) and not for that specific route as far as I can tell. Voting to reopen.

"driving from Germany through the south of Russia" -- where in the south of Russia are you planning to enter from Germany? Most of the Russian south is effectively a war zone these days.

@mustaccio OP clearly states “The trip will be when the war is over”
